# C++ Why numeric limits doesn't work for uint8_t and int8_t?

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

I recently noticed numeric_limits::max() and numeric_limits::min() don't seem to work for uint8_t and int8_t. Is there a reason for this or could it be a bug? I tried on my own computer using gcc compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::cout << "numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max() = " << numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int8_t>::max() = " << numeric_limits<int8_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() = " << numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max() = " << numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int16_t>::max() = " << numeric_limits<int16_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int16_t>::min() = " << numeric_limits<int16_t>::min() << std::endl; 

    std::cout << "numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() = " << numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int32_t>::max() = " << numeric_limits<int32_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int32_t>::min() = " << numeric_limits<int32_t>::min() << std::endl; 

    std::cout << "numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() = " << numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() = " << numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int64_t>::min() = " << numeric_limits<int64_t>::min() << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

gives output:

```
numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max() = �
numeric_limits<int8_t>::max() = 
numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() = �
numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max() = 65535
numeric_limits<int16_t>::max() = 32767
numeric_limits<int16_t>::min() = -32768
numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() = 4294967295
numeric_limits<int32_t>::max() = 2147483647
numeric_limits<int32_t>::min() = -2147483648
numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() = 18446744073709551615
numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() = 9223372036854775807
numeric_limits<int64_t>::min() = -9223372036854775808
```

Comment: On my system I have this `typedef unsigned char  uint8_t;`. What happens when you print a unsigned char, .e.g `unsigned char c = 'a'; std::cout << c;`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I get the output "a%". From other comments it seems like it's printing a char instead of an int? That could answer my question, but I don't know why it has this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does work. The output is interpreted as ASCII characters though. If you cast to int before you print, you will see the correct values:

```
std::cout << "numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max() = " << static_cast<int>(numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()) << std::endl; 
std::cout << "numeric_limits<int8_t>::max() = " << static_cast<int>(numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()) << std::endl; 
std::cout << "numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() = " << static_cast<int>(numeric_limits<int8_t>::min()) << std::endl;
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I feel slightly mislead by the name uint8 being a char and not an integer though. I wonder why they did it this way.

Comment: @Paradox A char is simply a 8 bit number. It's not a character. The output functions (cout/printf/...) interpret this number as character and print it like this. The name _"char"_ is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Paradox re: `and not an integer` a char **is** an integer. Character streams just treat integer types that are character types in a special way.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::cout << "numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max() = " << std::to_string(numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()) << std::endl; 
std::cout << "numeric_limits<int8_t>::max() = " << std::to_string(numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()) << std::endl; 
std::cout << "numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() = " << std::to_string(numeric_limits<int8_t>::min()) << std::endl;
```

try to convert them to string, before inserting them into cout.

Answer (score 2):

`int8` types are probably defined as `char`s, so don't print the values as `char`but as `int`s:

```
int main() {

    std::cout << "numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max() = " << (int)numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int8_t>::max() = " << (int)numeric_limits<int8_t>::max() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() = " << (int)numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend to use C style casts in C++ code.